# Get minimum difference of non-equal elements in integer array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I would like to analyze column of integer arrays in PostgreSQL (9.1). Using `intarray` ([docs here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/intarray.html)) I am able to calculate:

- array length
- minimum value
- maximum value
- number of unique elements

My query is:

```
    select 
        (array_length(string_to_array(num_partition,' ')::int[], 1))::smallint as part_len,
        icount(uniq(sort(string_to_array(num_partition,' ')::int[])))::smallint as part_unq,
        ((sort(string_to_array(num_partition,' ')::int[],'desc'))[1])::smallint as part_max,
        ((sort(string_to_array(num_partition,' ')::int[]))[1])::smallint as part_min    
    from 
        tmp.npart
```

Now I would like to calculate minimum difference between any non-equal elements. Example:

```
Array [1,5,5,10]
Expected result: 4 (because of 5-1 equals to 4)
```

I think I can calculate is using the following approach:

1. Get unique elements of array
2. Sort array
3. For each element in array substract A[I] - A[I+1]
4. Get maximum of the result in step 3

Example:

```
Input: [7,9,12,20,25,1,1,20,25]
1) Unique [1,7,9,12,20,25]
2) Sort (desc): [25,20,12,9,7,1] 
3) Diff A[i] - A[i+1]: [5,8,3,2,6]
4) Min: 2
```

Is there any simple way how to do this? I need to calculate this on a table with 150 000 000 rows.

Sample data (or [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c717e/1)):

```
create table tmp (intarr int[]);

insert into tmp values (ARRAY[1,1,3,6,9,25]);
insert into tmp values (ARRAY[10,20,30,50]);
insert into tmp values (ARRAY[1,4,8,15,21]);
insert into tmp values (ARRAY[1]);
insert into tmp values (ARRAY[1,1,1,1,9,9,9,9,20,20,20]);
```

Comment: It might be worth investigating whether it is more efficient to use a method that rejects differences of zero, rather than adding a unique operation on the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function to iterate over the array:

```
create or replace function array_min_diff(a int[])
returns int as
$$
declare
    min_diff int = null;
    i int = 2;
begin
    select array_agg(e order by e)
    from (
        select distinct e
        from unnest(a) s(e)
    ) s
    into a;

    loop
        min_diff = least(min_diff, a[i] - a[i - 1]);
        i := i + 1;
        exit when i > array_upper(a, 1);
    end loop;

    return min_diff;
end;
$$ language plpgsql immutable
```

Comment: Cool, I've changed the select section to `select uniq(sort(a)) into a;` hoping that intarray function is slightly faster than `unnest()`

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c717e/2)

```
select intarr, min(diff) min_diff
from (
    select
        intarr,
        i - lag(i) over(partition by intarr order by i) diff
    from (
        select distinct intarr, unnest(intarr) i
        from tmp
    ) s
) s
group by intarr
```

Comment: Thank you. I hoped for solution without `unnest` (because of table size), but I will test it and let you know.

Comment: @twn08 You could iterate over the array inside a plpgsql function. Don't know if it would be more efficient.